# Does facebook review only care about permission and not ethic?

Tags: facebook, review

Kind of a weird question :). 
In my understanding a Facebook review (in my case) is to allow my app to use extended permission (ex:user_photos).
Can I submit a basic app that does something simple(ex:upload a picture), submit for review, get validation, then create a totally different app?
Or will I have to resubmit when I make a change to my app?
Or will they scan each apps to see that the app didn't deviate?
I'm just being curious here :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs#permissions_app_updates

Although, if you change it to something completely different, you need to make sure it is still allowed. Don´t try to get a permission approved just to create something different that would not get the permission approved (just stating the obvious).

Btw, of course the App has to be about something serious, i don´t think you would get anything approved if you just present a very basic functionality without any sign how you want to use the permission later. A simple picture upload form without anything else may not get approved. Just build a basic prototype of your App before submitting.

Comment: Wow you were quick.
My question my other question is doesn't that cost a lot of resources for them to constantly verify that apps do not deviate to something else?

Comment: i don´t think they do that, but if people report it, they will surely take a look.  not sure why the question though, just be a honest and serious developer and don´t do it intentionally ;) - else, you may not just lose your app later, but also your developer account.

Comment: Isn't just sending a video of the app's workflow enough? Since they 'trust' you not to do something bad after.

Comment: i am still not sure where you want to go with this. if you want to build a serious app, you will have no problem at all. if something is "enough" or not, that question can only be answered by facebook, in the review process. just be very clear what you are building.

Comment: We also randomly re-review apps